# How do i add other fields on Abstract User

Tags: django, django-models, abstractuser

This is my model. When i make migrations it is not showing up on my admin page.

```html
class User(AbstractUser):
    # TODO User will be associated with one or more chama accounts
    id_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active_chama = models.ManyToManyField("Chama")
```

Comment: Have you followed the docs on how to configure your custom user model as the default user model and have you added a custom admin class?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in your `settings.py` if you use the AbstractUser model to create a custom one.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myApp.User"
```

Here is the relevant part in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

**Edit:**

Like stated in the comments you will have to register your custom model in your custom user apps `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```